# How to determine source directories priority in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following fragment inside my `build.gradle`

```
 main {
        resources.srcDir "src/main/resources-$env"
    }
```

The folder

```
src/main/resources
```

is source by default.

I want to achieve that `src/main/resources-$env` has a priority than just `resources`.

Now If I have a file with name `config.properties`

and in some source-code I write:

```
Properties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('config.properties');
```

path

```
src/main/resources/config.properties
```

has higher priority.

1. Is this priority guaranteed ?
2. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it like:

```
main {
    // important to use '=' so you set rather than add
    resources.srcDirs = ["src/main/resources-$env", "src/main/resources"]
}
```

Or you might want to merge resources together into a single folder

```
task mergeResources(type: Copy) {
    def envResources = fileTree("src/main/resources-$env")
    def defaultResources = fileTree("src/main/resources").minus(envResources)

    from envResources
    from defaultResources
    into "$buildDir/mergedResources"
}

main {
    resources.srcDirs = ["$buildDir/mergedResources"]
}

// wire the task into the DAG
compile.dependsOn mergeResources
```